# Drying up controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dry

I have a ContentController inside which i have these two actions doing similar functionality. How can reduce the code duplication for these functions?

```
def like
  like = Like.create(like: params[:like], user: current_user, content: @content)
  if like.valid?
    flash[:success] = "Your vote was successful!"
    redirect_to :back
  else
    flash[:danger]= "You can like a content only once"
    redirect_to :back
  end
end

def review
  review = Review.create(body: params[:body], user: current_user, content: @content)
  if review.valid?
    flash[:success] = "Your review was successful!"
    redirect_to :back
  else
    flash[:danger]= "You can review a content only once"
    redirect_to :back
  end      
end
```

Comment: "Similar" and "same" are not synonyms. You can only DRY code to the point where you're not duplicating code that does exactly the same thing.

Comment: Make a `likes_controller` and `reviews_controller`.  Give them each a create method and submit remotely instead of redirecting back.

Comment: Are you sending both like and body parameter in every action,I mean for both like and review ?

Comment: @rakeshpatra No those parameters belong to separate actions .. for eg user likes a content and user posts a review. like is a boolean parameter abd body is text

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it in this way,but make sure that your parameter(like/review) is same as action name.

```
 def common_action(action)
     object = Object.const_get(action.camelcase).create(action.to_sym => params[action.to_sym])
 end
```